# Weather widget in lock screen

Tags: android, widget, lockscreen

First of all, thanks for read this and for your answers. I´m newbie with Android and I´m trying to make a weather widget, well I have it, but I´m trying to put it on the lock screen and I don´t know how. Could you recommend me some tutorial, example, web or whatever to learn? I have been searching for something but I haven´t found anything.

Thanks.

Comment: Ya follow the example. https://github.com/ChiragSavsani/FlashLightWidget

Comment: Adenda SDK may help u to work ur app in lock screen try this [http://www.adendamedia.com/]